# pHp session error?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I've been trying to figure out why my code isn't working on my PC at home using XAMPP 1.8.2 while at work I've been using 1.7.2. I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_is_registered() in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginscript\session1.php on line 5
```

What I have on line 5.

```
if(!session_is_registered(username)){
header("location:index.php");
}
```

I would imagine it having to do something with pHp version? Cheers

A user has requested to see my code..

```
<?php 
session_start()
//--- Authenticate code begins here ---
//checks if the login session is true
if(!session_is_registered(username));{
header("location:index.php");
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

// --- Authenticate code ends here ---


 include ('header.php'); ?>
```

Comment: _This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0._

Comment: ; after session_start()

Comment: You have some errors mate, and remove ; on the line where you have the IF clause

Comment: @0riginal I did that mate and got the same error listed above, Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_is_registered()

Comment: try using if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) instead of session_is_registered - you also have a few syntax errors, such as the semicolon on the if statement.

Comment: @user3819677 this was just an error I saw in your code. like other users already mentoined you shouldn't use session_is_registered()

Comment: @user3819677 please see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24649670/3176270

Comment: @Kermani I've changed my code to this

Comment: @user3819677 ok, so please select your answer that is http://stackoverflow.com/a/24649670/3176270 by clicking at the tick near down and up buttons

Comment: @Kermani The problem wasen't the ; and still haven't figured out why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Halloei in the comments, you said at home you are using Xampp 1.8.2 and at work 1.7.2 - if you have a look at the [Xampp version history](http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/xampp-version-history-apache-mysql-php/) 1.8.2 comes with PHP 5.4 whereas 1.7.2 comes with PHP 5.3 and the [`session_is_registered`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php) function was `DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0`. This is the cause of the error you are seeing.

To correct this you can update your code to something like the following:

```
<?php 
session_start();

//--- Authenticate code begins here ---

//checks if the login session is true
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("location:index.php");
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

// --- Authenticate code ends here ---

include ('header.php'); 
?>
```

This uses [`isset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if the value `username` is set in the session array.

Answer (score 0):

First look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php)

you should add **session_start()** at the beginning of page

and to set a value to session your code should be something like this

> $_SESSION["username"] = "John";

and to get value:

```
$username=$_SESSION["name"];
```

**YOUR PROBLEML is semicolon ";":**

```
session_start()  //error
session_start(); //true
```

Comment: Got this error when I did that  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginscript\session1.php on line 5

Comment: @user3819677 please put all of your code to check it.

Comment: <?php 
session_start()
//--- Authenticate code begins here ---
//checks if the login session is true
if(!session_is_registered(username));{
header("location:index.php");
}
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

// --- Authenticate code ends here ---


 include ('header.php'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your own session_is_registered function if this is being used widely in your site.

```
function session_is_registered($username)
{
     $registered = false;
     if(//Expression here to check if $username is in the $_SESSION array)
     {
          $registered = true;
     }
     return $registered;
}
```

Then make sure to include this function where the old registered function is being used.
Be warned though if you move this function to an older version of PHP it might throw an error since this function is still available in older versions.

Comment: the problem was ; semicolon

Comment: @Kermani as mentioned by halloei, Xampp 1.8.2 comes with php 5.4 where this function no longer exists. So although there was a missing semi-colon it is not the only problem..

Comment: @Kermani He included the error message from PHP with it, it said undefined function. So it was either a misspelled function or a deprecated one. Since I saw some answers about it being deprecated I thought he could use this approach. Like I said if this was included on that way on multiple locations through his site. Redefining the function would be the best way. But altogether Boreded's version to solve it seemed better for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

your code is this

```
session_start()
//--- Authenticate code begins here ---
//checks if the login session is true
if(!session_is_registered(username));{
header("location:index.php");
}
```

and you need to rectify the colon  like this   colon after session_start  and no colon after if condition

```
session_start();
//--- Authenticate code begins here ---
//checks if the login session is true
if(!session_is_registered(username)) {
header("location:index.php");
}
```